# Using information in an SQL array to provide a result in a different field

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to display the gang name of a user if their steam id is found in the list of players.

[Gang Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVa7y.png)

I can get other details to pull but this is the first time I have tried to pull from an array.

```
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <?php
    $sid = $steamprofile['steamid'];
    $bob = ("[`$sid`]");    
    $sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `gangs` WHERE `members` = (' . explode(',', $bob) . ')";

                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                            echo "<div class='big'>" . $row["name"] . "</div>";
                        };

   ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">Gang Management</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your member column seems to be a *JSON array* text field. You can't directly search within it unless you use  TEXT search methods.

```
$query = 'select * from users where members LIKE "%\"' . $steamId . '\"%"';
```

Comment: This worked, this is what I used: `<?php
$sid = $steamprofile['steamid'];
$bob = ("[`$sid`]"); 
$sql = 'select * from gangs where members LIKE "%\"' . $bob . '\"%"';
                     
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

       echo "<div class='big'>" . $row["name"] . "</div>";
                        };

?>`